# Break from foreach in background worker

Tags: c#, foreach

I am using Entity Framework to iterate through table in BackgroundWorker

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    using (var db = new LibraryLogModel())
    {
        int count = 0;
        var table = db.FrontOfficeAction.AsNoTracking()
            .OrderBy(s => s.FrontOfficeSessionId)
            .ThenBy(d => d.ActionDateTime);
        foreach (var row in table)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;                                            
                return;
            }
            count++;
            _actionAnalyzer.AnalyzeAction(row);
            if (count % 1000 == 0)
            {
                worker.ReportProgress(count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorting takes only 30 seconds, then foreach working correctly. ReportProgress() updates progress bar and label. When the analysis ends, RunWorkerCompleted event raised, and everything is fine, no exceptions. But if I click cancel button and call CancelAsync() during analysis, some strange magic happens.

worker.CancellationPending is true, but RunWorkerCompleted event is not raised, and I get an SqlErrorCollection exception after timeout.

```
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
  Class=11
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  HResult=-2146232060
  LineNumber=0
  Message=Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding
  Number=-2
  Procedure=""
  Server=.\SQLEXPRESS
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  State=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryCloseInternal(Boolean closeReader)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Close()
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.Dispose()
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.Finally()
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.Dispose()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.Dispose()
       at ECatalogRecommendations.Form1.bw_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
InnerException: 
   ErrorCode=-2147467259
   HResult=-2147467259
   Message=Timeout expired
   NativeErrorCode=258
   InnerException:
```

If wrap it in try-catch, RunWorkerCompleted would be raised, but only after the same timeout.

I tried to use break instead of return, but it didn't break the foreach loop at all, and I got the same exception.

I run background worker as

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_worker.IsBusy)
    {
        int size;
        using (var db = new LibraryLogModel())
        {
            size = db.FrontOfficeAction.Count();
        }
        progressBar.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar.Maximum = size;
        _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to show us the inner exception. Click [Copy Exception Details To Clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/) and add that to your question inside a code block.

Comment: Your text is difficult to understand. Are you sure, that you reach the return statement? The question is: Are you sure, that worker.CancellationPending is true? For testing, you can change the code in: if(true){..}

Comment: Your query contains an OrderBy so it'll probably take up 99% of the time of the DoWork(). How important is it to AnalyzeAction() in a particular order?

Comment: Also, the very core purpose of EF is to keep you away from `row` and `table`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks, I added StackTrace

Comment: @SeanStayn Yes, worker.CancellationPending is true after calling CancelAsync()

Comment: @HenkHolterman I need OrderBy to analyze actions with similar session one by one without loading entire table into memory cause there are 3 million rows

Comment: Then up your timeout setting.

Comment: I did not ask for the stack trace, I asked for the `Copy Exception Details to the Clipbord` output. That will give us the stack trace, the exception message, and (the part that we actually need) any inner exceptions.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Done.

Comment: You are (still) asking about the break and cancellation. But I seriously doubt this will run at all. What happens when you sit back and wait for an hour? Ever seen the ReportProgress() doing anything?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sorting takes only 30 seconds, then foreach working correctly. ReportProgress() updates progress bar and label. When the analysis ends (it takes only 3 minutes, not an hour), RunWorkerCompleted event raised, and everything is fine, no exceptions. But if I click cancel button and call CancelAsync() during analysis, some strange magic happens.

Comment: Then better add that to the question, this is relevant info but comments don't count here.

Comment: I think you have to add the rest code.. If you call return and the analysis works async with fire and forget, then you can get this issue.